# How to create custom color palette?

Tags: python

I want a color palette similar to texture paint means when I select the color in the color palette it should change the color in the color picker. And I want the custom colors in the color palette.

[image]

```
import bpy


class ColorPalettePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Color Palette"
    bl_idname = "PT_ColorPalette"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tool'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        if context.tool_settings.image_paint.palette:
            layout.template_palette(context.tool_settings.image_paint, "palette", color=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColorPalettePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColorPalettePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can get information about how it is structured in the UI using developer extras after you enable them in the preferences. Right click in the field and choose "Edit Source". This will open the corresponding UI script with the line cursor set at the line responsible for drawing the layout element.

eg after right clicking > Edit source in the color picker a file called *properties_paint_common.py*  opens up in the script editor.

[image]

A few references that you will need :

[layout.template_palette](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_palette)

[layout.template_color_picker](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_color_picker)

[bpy.types.Palette](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Palette.html#bpy.types.Palette)

[bpy.types.Palette.colors](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Palette.html#bpy.types.Palette.colors)

[bpy.types.Palette.colors.active](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PaletteColors.html#bpy.types.PaletteColors.active)

[bpy.types.Palette.colors.active.color](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PaletteColor.html#bpy.types.PaletteColor.color)

Here's the script.

```
import bpy


class MyPaletteGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_palette: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Palette)


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        my_palette_group = context.scene.my_palette_group
        my_palette = my_palette_group.my_palette
        if my_palette and my_palette.colors and my_palette.colors.active:
            active_color = my_palette.colors.active
            layout.template_color_picker(active_color, "color", value_slider=True)
            layout.prop(active_color, "color", text="")        
        layout.template_ID(my_palette_group, "my_palette", new="palette.new")
        if my_palette_group:
            layout.template_palette(my_palette_group, "my_palette", color=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPaletteGroup)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_palette_group = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPaletteGroup)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_palette_group
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyPaletteGroup)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

It's not an exact replica of the color picker in the tools properties because there is a notion of secondary color that is not in any way tied to the palette nor the color picker. You can add it independantly of the palette and color picker.

Note the screen can be a little buggy when you click on some color stamps, I don't exactly know why but I think it has to do with the active color being null for a frame.