# How to change the base color of a material when I change the color in the color palette?

Tags: python

I want to change the base color of the material when I change the color in the color palette.

Related to this question: [How to create custom color palette?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303808/how-to-create-custom-color-palette)

I tried the update callback in the pointer property but it doesn't change the base color of the material `bpy.data.materials['Material']`

Comment: Well you need to provide a bit more information about this, it's possible using a callback on the property I guess, but it depends on a lot of factors. What's the node setup of your material ? Do you wanty to change the active object's material, or a specific material by name, etc.